# How to export function with return type std::map in c++

Tags: c++, function, stdmap

I have a DLL project and a CLR project in visual c++.

The DLL project is the one that exporting std::map type function. And I will call that function from my CLR project.

From DLL project,
staff.h

```
#ifdef STAFFS_EXPORTS
#define STAFFS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define STAFFS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <string>
#include <map>

namespace Staffs {
    // other exported functions
    ....
    //
    extern "C" STAFFS_API auto GetStaffMap() -> std::map<int, std::string>;
}
```

staff.cpp

```
namespace Staffs {
   std::map<int, std::string> staffMap;

   extern "C" auto GetStaffMap() -> std::map<int, std::string> {
        return staffMap;
    }

   void display_json(json::value const & jvalue, utility::string_t const & prefix)
    {
      // some code being skipped here
      .......
      //
      staffMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
    }
}
```

But when I tried to compile my DLL project, I got some errors:

```
Error   C2526   'GetStaffMap': C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'std::map<int,std::string,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'  AmsCppRest  c:\users\laptop-attendance\source\repos\amscpprest\amscpprest\staff.h   18  

Error   C2556   'std::map<int,std::string,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> Staffs::GetStaffMap(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void Staffs::GetStaffMap(void)'   AmsCppRest  c:\users\laptop-attendance\source\repos\amscpprest\amscpprest\staff.cpp 38  

Error   C2371   'Staffs::GetStaffMap': redefinition; different basic types  AmsCppRest  c:\users\laptop-attendance\source\repos\amscpprest\amscpprest\staff.cpp 38
```

I can't find any solution related to this problem.

Comment: What is CLR project? Is it written in C? If so, you cannot access C++ `std::map` from within. The same holds for accessing map values, which are of C++ type `std::string`. You would need to wrap the whole functionality of map with some C API that finds value for `int` key and returns plain C string as `char*`.

Comment: @DanielLangr AFAIK, CLR is .NET, so it could be in (kind of) C++, C#, VB, or something else. One can import C functions from a DLL in a CLR project, but I don't know about C++. Might be tricky.

Comment: I successfully export import some functions from my DLL project into my CLR project. Only this one function that has a return type of std::map that I have a problem.

Comment: Isn't the problem that he is trying to export a C++ class in a function that is marked for C linkage?

Comment: Btw your second error says that you overloaded the `GetStaffMap` function, which is not allowed in C linkage as C doesn't support overloading.

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot export it using extern 'C'? If so, how would I export it?

Comment: First of all, remove the `extern "C"` in your source file. This is causing your 2nd and 3rd error

Comment: It works now. I just removed extern "C" for this function. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot export non-trivial C++ classes with C linkage, and the compiler is telling you so in the error message.

The question is why do you use C linkage in the first place? If you don't have to use C linkage, don't use it. This will make things just more complicated as you need wrappers for almost everything. As long as you use the same compiler you'll be fine.

So in your header **and** source files, remove the `extern "C"` from the signature if you can (in either case: remove it from the source file, or else you redefine the function there which causes the latter 2 errors).

If you cannot remove the `extern "C"` part, try returning a void pointer (`void*`) instead of `std::map` and cast it to a map pointer in your CLR project. But this will force you to use managed C++ as CLR language.

I don't know what your CLR project is, but if it's written in managed C++ you can use all standard C++ types there aswell so C++ linkage is perfectly fine. If your CLR project is in a different language, like C#, consider making another project in managed C++ and use that as a wrapper like `C# dll <--> managed C++ dll <--> C++ dll`.

Comment: I use c++ in my CLR. Anyway thank you. I solved my problem when I removed extern "C" for that function.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with this type of problem, but how about creating a function like:

```
extern "C" STAFFS_API const char* GetStaffMapValue(int key);
```

and

```
extern "C" const char* GetStaffMapValue(int key) {
   auto it = staffMap.find(key);
   if (it == staffMap.end())
      return nullptr;
   else 
      return it->second.c_str();          
}
```

You can of course similarly create wrappers for map modifiers, e.g., for inserting new elements.